# matlab - while loop until values converge

Tags: matlab, loops

I need to solve the following equation:

```
old_val = 0.4*U_Z/(log(5/new_val));
```

where

```
new_val = 0.11*1.5e-5./old_val;
```

In order to calculate new_val and old_val I need to write a loop which calculates new_val and old_val and then takes the true value of new_val as when new_val is 0.001% of the previous new_val.

I have though about using a while loop to do this, which I think might work. I am a bit confused, though, on how to start the while loop, should I have:

```
while abs((new_val(i) - val_prev(i))) > 0.000001     
    old_val = 0.4*W(i)/(log(5/new_val));
    dummy = new_val(i);
    new_val = 0.11*1.5e-5./old_val;
    val_prev(i) = dummy;
end
```

or

```
    while abs((new_val(i) - val_prev(i))) / abs(val_prev(i)) > 0.000001     
    old_val = 0.4*W(i)/(log(5/new_val));
    dummy = new_val(i);
    new_val = 0.11*1.5e-5./old_val;
    val_prev(i) = dummy;
end
```

where

```
val_prev = new_val*1.1;
```

which is used to initiate the iteration. The while loop is used to continue running the loop until new_val and val_prev are within 0.001% of each other.

Comment: From your description, I think you should use percentage change and not absolute change. Read [this](http://www.math.umb.edu/~joan/MATHQ114/change.htm) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to solve this equation for `x`:

```
x =  0.4*U_Z/log( 5/(0.11*1.5e-5./x) )
```

with `U_Z` some constant. If that is indeed what you want to do, I'd re-write it as

```
x * log( 5*x/1.65e-6 ) - 0.4*U_Z == 0
```

and solve like this:

```
x_sol = fzero(@(x) x .* log( 5*x/1.65e-6 ) - 0.4*U_Z, 1)
```

or, if you insist, use your own Newton-Raphson scheme:

```
fx   = @(x) x .* log( 5*x/1.65e-6 ) - 0.4*U_Z
dfdx = @(x) log(x) + 15.9242;

x = 1;
f = fx(x);
while abs(f) > 1e-6   
    x = x-f/dfdx(x);
    f = fx(x);
end
```

But I'm not sure if this is what you want...